# django-cms - how to know which apphooks are active

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a page which can be fed with plugins and apphooks.

it's like a page which can be news-page, horoscope-page and pictures-page which all are app(hook)s with plugins.

in cms_plugins.py of news app I want to render mixed items like.. 2 news, 2 horoscopes and 2 pics.. which means I need to make sure that those 3 apps are really activated in this page.

this is the `render` part of my news plugin:

```
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    news = MyNews.objects.order_by('-id')[:2]
    #horoscopes = Astro.objects.order_by('-id')[:2]
    #pics = Pics.objects.order_by('-id')[:2]
    context.update({
        "instance": instance,
        "news": news,
        "placeholder": placeholder
    })
    return context
```

How can I know the active apphooks? e.g. how can I know if horoscopes-page and pics-page exists so that i can render them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the `Page` Model of cms and solved the issue this way:

```
from cms.models import Page

def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
   news = MyNews.objects.order_by('-id')[:2]

   lang = context['request'].LANGUAGE_CODE
   #check if horoscope in current context language is activated for the current domain
   if Page.objects.filter(application_namespace__iexact='astro', languages__contains=lang).exists():
        horoscopes = Astro.objects.order_by('-updated')[:2]

  context.update({
       "instance": instance,
       "news": news,
       "placeholder": placeholder
   })
   return context
```